# Use #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash for Ubuntu-OSX compatibility and ease of use & POSIX

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, osx, posix

I know that I can use either as the first line of scripts to invoke the desired shell.

Would `#!/bin/sh` be recommended if compatibility with all unix systems is an absolute requirement?

In my case the only OS' I care about are Ubuntu (Debian) and OSX.
Given that, could I use `#!/bin/bash` and be assured it would work on both systems?
Would this also make it easier to use scripts with more modern and clearer syntax for commands? Does using `#!/bin/sh` also relate to using POSIX ?

Comment: Probably worth noting that many distros have started merging `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. Resultingly, it's probably better to use `#!/usr/bin/env <shname>` for portability these days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For starters, if you can make the assumption that Bash is preinstalled (which, to my knowledge is the case on all the systems you list), use the following hashbang to be compatible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

this invokes whatever `bash` happens to be configured, no matter whether it's in `/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

While on most systems across a wide range (including AIX, Solaris, several BSD flavors), `bash` ended up in different locations, `env` always ended up in `/usr/bin/env`. The trick, however, is not mine but from the author of the Bash Cookbook.

Anyway, yes Bash would allow you to use some "modern" features that make your life easier.

For example the double brackets:

```
[[ -f "/etc/debian_version" ]] && echo "This is a Debian flavor"
```

whereas in traditional shell dialects you'd have to resort to:

```
test -f "/etc/debian_version" && echo "This is a Debian flavor"
```

but the best about the double brackets is that they allow regular expressions for matching. The [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php) will give you many tricks in that direction.

You can also use quite convenient expressions like `$((2**10))` or other arithmetic expressions inline with the `$((expression))` syntax.

Using backticks for subshells is fine, albeit a bit outdated. But the nesting capabilities of `$(command ...)` invocations are way more convenient as you won't have to escape many things at different subshell levels.

These are but a few things Bash gives you over the traditional common POSIX `sh` syntax.

But if you want more power on the shell (not just in scripts), also have a look at `zsh`.

Comment: Bash is a very useful tool but be careful not to use it for starting services that might be vulnerable to a Bash scripting bug, e.g. https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-6271. Stick to `sh` for such tasks.

Comment: Rick-777 that vulnerability was vastly overblown and in my opinion your comment is FUD. If a system service runs under bash it is in no way vulnerable to that bug. It is only vulnerable to that bug if it forks off a bash process while allowing remote users direct access to one or more environment variables, like in FastCGI, and even then only on unpatched versions of bash. On systems with `sh` linked to `bash`, the vulnerability will not be mitigated by using `sh`.

Answer (score 11):

In Debian and Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is `dash`, which is a POSIX-compliant shell. If you specify `#!/bin/sh`, you must limit yourself to POSIX statements in your script. (The advantage being that `dash` starts faster than `bash`, so your script can get its job done in less time.)

On many (most?) other Linux systems, `/bin/sh` is `bash`, which is why many scripts are written with `#!/bin/sh` as their shebang line even though they use `bash` extensions.

If you want to use `bash` extensions, the safest approach on all systems is to specify `#!/bin/bash`; that way you're explicitly stating your dependency on `bash`. You *need* to do this on Debian and Ubuntu. As an added bonus, when started as `/bin/sh` `bash` de-activates some extensions (see [the description of `bash` POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) for details); so specifying `#!/bin/bash` is necessary to get the full benefit of `bash`.

On OS X `/bin/bash` is available too, and `/bin/sh` is `bash`. Specifying `#!/bin/bash` will work fine there as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, both OSX and Linux will come with `/bin/bash`. You should be perfectly safe. However, that is *not* POSIX. The POSIX shell is at `/bin/sh` on most (all?) systems and that is the most portable approach and the only way to be POSIX compatible.

Note that while on many systems `/bin/sh` points to `bash`, on others it can point to different shells. It's a symlink to `dash` on Debian and Ubuntu for example. Also, even if `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash`, the behavior of the shell changes when it is called as `sh` (from `man bash`, emphasis mine):

> **If bash is invoked with the name sh, it  tries  to  mimic  the 
>   startup    behavior  of  historical  versions  of sh as closely as
>   possible, while    conforming to the POSIX standard as well.**  When
>   invoked as an  interac‐    tive  login  shell, or a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option,    it first attempts to read and
>   execute commands  from  /etc/profile  and    ~/.profile,  in  that 
>   order.   The  --noprofile  option may be used to    inhibit this
>   behavior.  When invoked as an interactive shell  with  the    name 
>   sh,  bash  looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is
>   defined, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read 
>   and    execute.  Since a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read
>   and execute commands from any other startup files, the --rcfile
>   option has  no    effect.   **A  non-interactive  shell  invoked  with
>   the name sh does not    attempt to read any other startup files. When  invoked  as  sh,  bash enters posix mode after the startup
>   files are read.**

Answer (score 2):

If compatibility with "all Unix systems" is an absolute requirement -- *and if it isn't, why are you writing a shell script?* -- then, yes, you should be using `#! /bin/sh`, because Bash is not guaranteed to be installed *anywhere*, let alone in `/bin`.

It's actually much, much worse than that.  If you need compatibility to *all* Unix systems, that includes things like Solaris and AIX that *froze their shell environments* circa 1995.  Which means you have to use things like the old-fashioned `sort +N` syntax -- that *newer* systems have dropped!  And it also means no shell functions, no arrays, no `[[ ... ]]`, no `${foo#glob}`, no `$(( ... ))` for arithmetic, possibly no `$( ... )`-style command substitution, small and undocumented upper limits on how big input can get, ...

You can probably get away with not bothering with *that* much compatibility, but if it's even an issue in the first place, I strongly recommend you consider a language that is less terrible than shell.  The basic Perl interpreter is *more* likely to be available than Bash.

Comment: Thanks.  As originally stated "In my case the only OS' I care about are Ubuntu (Debian) and OSX.".  These are the only 2 systems I've used (and I use them a lot) in the last 5 years, so that is 'why' I am writing a shell script that would only work on them.  I have no need at all for a universal script and the limitations it would present.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant In that case, you don't need to, and should not, write a shell script.  You should instead use any of the multitude of *better* scripting languages that are an option when you don't need total portability.