# An official standard / convention for a file extension for shell scripts to source

Tags: shell-script, shell, standard, conventions

I was wondering if there is a convention for file type extensions for shell scripts you want to source instead of run. For example:

1. If I want to run this script in a subshell.

   ```
    ./script.sh
   ```
2. If I want to remember to run this script from the current shell.

   ```
    . script.source
   ```

Is there **a convention** (like POSIX for example) for a filetype in the second example? Something like `.source` or `.sourceme`?

---

#### Update

This question does not ask about any opinion. I clearly stated that I would like to know if there is a standardized file extension for this kind of scripts. This question is even less opinion-based than [this well received question on a similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182882/128489) ([Use .sh or .bash extension for bash scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182882/128489)).

Comment: Some people think that shell scripts that can be run a executables (i.e. they begin with `#!/bin/sh` or similar should have no extension, because the user should not need to care about what language the underlying script was written in.

Comment: Depends what it's for, you can have env , rc , conf etc

Comment: @the_velour_fog Yeah, I've read about it. I am curious if there is a naming convention apart from the `#!/bin/sh` thing and removal of the unnecessary executable bit from permissions.

Comment: @the_velour_fog Typically you want the extension to give an idea of what the file contains.

Comment: @123 it depends, sometimes once you build something thats  useful and put it into `$PATH` , you come to use all the time , so its like, `ps`, `ls`, `curl` and all the other commands, then you start to build shell completion functions around it, I find its ok to drop the extension. But yes, when you are sourcing a shell script, that are not executable by themselves, I would not `chmod +x` them, and I would name them `script.sh`. also I often assign an extension purely because if I don't I won't get syntax highlighting on my editor.

Comment: @the_velour_fog You don't source any of those executable you mentioned... I don't know what point you are trying to make.

Comment: There is no convention.  If you are in a company or if you are collaborating in a share project (eg opensource) then you might have local standards to conform with, but there is no de facto convention.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski You can update your editor to accept whatever extension you want for highlighting.

Comment: I updated the question to explain why I feel it is unfair to put this question on-hold.

Comment: The word ["convention"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convention) (meaning #2) is what is probably leading towards "opinion-based" answers. The [open group spec for source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) does not enforce any naming standard.

Comment: I'm not aware of any convention, but my personal habit is to name such files with a .inc extension, indicating they are to be INCluded (sourced) in other scripts, and not to be executed directly. I think using a .sh or .bash extension is actually UNhelpful due to all of the people who think it should be used for commands executed at the shell prompt.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd use `.sh` (for files in the POSIX `sh` language, `.bash` for non-sh-compatible `bash` files, that is the extension identifies the language the script is written in) for files intended to be sourced (or more generally not intended to be executed), and no extension for files that are meant to be executed.

You can also add a:

```
#! /bin/echo Please-source
```

she-bang, so that when executed by mistake (though I'd expect those files should not be given execution permissions, which would already prevent execution), you get a notice that it should be sourced instead.

Comment: You can also exit if the script is not sourced (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2683279/4694621)

Comment: I prefer `/bin/false` to `/bin/echo` as the former ensures a 'fail' exit code if the file is accidentally executed (but you do lose the text feedback you get with echo)

Answer (score 4):

In case of source files, i think the best way is .conf for files that configure your script and .shlib or .shlibs for files that have functions or other utils.

If you want to prevent your script to run with the wrong shell, and hashbang is not enough for you, you can use this:

```
if [ "$(readlink "/proc/$$/exe")" != "/bin/bash" ]; then
      echo >&2 "CAUTION: Wrong interpreter detected. You must use bash."
      exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If you're going to use the Linux-specific `/proc/$$/exe`, you might  as well do it as `case $(readlink "/proc/$$/exe") in */bash)...`, though here, I'd simply use: `if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]`. (`echo` should be `echo >&2`). (I like you `.conf` or `.shlibs` (but for sh files) extensions though it may not help syntax highlighters that rely on the extension).

Comment: Yes i see this .shlibs, in some kind of program that i donwload, but i dont remember, so i started using this. Thank you very much for the tip, i will edit the question with the readlink version much more beautiful. ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Syntax highlighting may be triggered through meta-data in the files themselves (atleast for Emacs and Vim), so the choice of filename extension is irrelevant in that respect.